# Error: Cannot find module 'browserslist' when I run the npm run build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm using latest version of react-scripts npm package i.e. 4.0.3 in my react project and it has a vulnerabilities with one of his dependency package called browserslist, I was trying to resolve this vulnerability by adding this package under the resolutions section in my package.json file. I tried to override the package version with the help of preinstall command **npx npm-force-resolutions**  and it will install the version we specified under the resolutions.
My package.json file will be

```html
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
    "build": "react-scripts build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "browserslist": "4.16.6"
  }
}
```

1. When I run the **npm install** the preinstall script will run and it will installing the browserslist package version after that I tried to check the list available vulnerabilities with **npm audit** command and I got 0 vulnerabilities.
   Refer https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp1Sf.png to install command view.
   Refer https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dLJz.png to audit command view
2. After that I tried to run the **npm run build** command and it will took build script from my package.json file. The build is failing with following error.
   Refer https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt3OE.png to build command view

I did lot of research on this from past 2 weeks but no luck at all. I'm definitely missing something after this. It would be great if anyone can help me on this it will be really appreciate.

Answer (score 6):

Run this in your terminal:

```
npm i browserslist
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete your nodemodules folder and package.lock.json file and run npm install.

Comment: Hi Khan, I did these things as well but no luck

Comment: Can you share your repo

Answer (score 0):

Delete your nodemodules folder and run npm install.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).